# Can we have the new answers posted notification on the mobile site?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, notification-bar

It can take a long time to enter a decent answer via the mobile site. Code formatting, links and research are all harder.

Is it possible to get the "new answers have been posted" notification on there so I can check the other answer(s), give up and move on (if the other answers are up to snuff, obviously).

It is disappointing to have spent time on an answer to post it and see a very similar one there that was posted 5 minutes ago - my answer is now just noise, and I could have spent the time on another question.

Comment: That's one of the reasons why I'd rather have a small laptop than a smartphone.

Comment: My trousers aren't big enough to hold a small laptop unfortunately.

Comment: My guess is "No" because of the extra requests it'd require, but since this happened to me the other day I wouldn't mind it myself.